Can we see the built heaven
I have a question about a verse. I have read somewhere that the built sky is far and can't be seen but does Quran 50:6 mean we can see it because we are asked to observe how the sky is built and that there aren't any cracks in it
Quran 50:6: "Have they not looked at the heaven above them - how We structured it and adorned it and [how] it has no rifts?"
I know the translation uses the word structured but the word in arabic translates to built
